# Android Studio 2.0, the developed app is debuggable but not shown on the app drawer

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing the android app on the Android Studio 2.0.
I'm able to run and debug my app from the studio, but on the phone launcher app list the app is not shown. I can't run the app directly on the phone.
Why ?

Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivitySplash"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.myapp.profile" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
The lines

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

should be under separate **intent-filter**
For other intents i had to open another **intent-filter**.

Answer (score 0):

Is your phone enabled for debuggable mode? If not go to Settings -> About Phone and click "Build Number" 7 times. You're now a developer!!

Now go to Settings -> Developer options and enable USB debugging

Comment: I'm already in the debugger mode. I'm able to run and debug my app from the studio.

Answer (score 0):

As you are able to run & debug the app when its connected with studio, i guess you are missing the entry (Launcher) in manifest.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.Launcher" />
```

try to include this inside activity tag as shown below

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Note: the reason why its running when connected is the launcher activity is manually set in the run configuration.

Comment: I do have these lines on my main activity, as well as <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>